# Polarized proton beam

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-spin, protons, accelerator-physics

Can someone explain to me or point me towards some references about how can one obtain experimentally a polarized proton beam. I find many talks about using siberian snakes to preserve the polarization of a proton in an experiment, but they don't talk about how you polarize the proton in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: Something like https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4215952 might help.

Comment: This question would be clearer if you explained what a siberian snake is.

Comment: Do you have a beam energy (or at least an energy order of magnitude) in mind? Do you want to know how such beams are produced at a particular facility, or are you hoping for a general review of polarized particle production?

Comment: @G.Smith siberian snakes are used to preserve the polarization of a beam once that is achieved. It is not really related to my question (that step comes after you polarize the beam)

Comment: @rob any method would work. I just want to know at least one method to obtain a polarized beam. Increasing the energy should be straightforward using the right electric field. I just want to know how to get a bunch of polarized protons in the first place.

Comment: You need a polarized proton source: https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/e08/papers/tuobm03.pdf